# Change item checkbox on ListBox selection change

Tags: c#, silverlight, templates, checkbox, listbox

I have a ListBox created by ItemTemplate and Binding

```
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="{Binding AppResources.SettingsSubpage2, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}">
            <Grid>
                <ListBox x:Name="DayOfWeekSelector" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DayOfWeekTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding DayOfWeekElementList}" Foreground="{StaticResource AppForegroundColor}" LostFocus="DayOfWeekSelector_LostFocus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="420" />
            </Grid>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

Template code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
   <!--- ... --->
<DataTemplate x:Key="DayOfWeekTemplate">
        <Grid Height="65" Width="332">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}" Tag="{Binding}" d:LayoutOverrides="Width, Height" BorderBrush="{StaticResource AppBackgroundColor}" Background="{StaticResource ScheduleBackgroundAccentsColor}" Grid.Column="0" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" />
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  d:LayoutOverrides="Width"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskCounter, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource DayOfWeekCounter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
   <!--- ... --->
```

And it's working fine. I've got all my items on the list. Checkboxes are binded to appropriate elements (clicking on it is changing proper value).

But by default ListBox can be also selected. Selection high-light TextBox binded to Name but don't change CheckBox (binded to IsActive). How can I tie item selection changing to checkbox state changing (in Silverlight)?

## Edit:

```
public partial class SettingsPage : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    public List<DayOfWeekElement> DayOfWeekList
    {
        get
        {
            return CyberSyncPlanBase.Instance.DayOfWeekElementList;
        }
        set
        {
            CyberSyncPlanBase.Instance.DayOfWeekElementList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DayOfWeekList");
        }
    }

   public SettingsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DayOfWeekSelector.DataContext = CyberSyncPlanBase.Instance;

    }

 private void DayOfWeekSelector_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DayOfWeekElement dowe = (DayOfWeekElement) DayOfWeekSelector.SelectedItem;

        if (dowe != null)
            dowe.IsActive = (dowe.IsActive) ? false : true;
    }
```

And in singleton INotifyPropertyChanged i've implemented in the same way:

```
    private List<DayOfWeekElement> dayOfWeekElementList;
    public List<DayOfWeekElement> DayOfWeekElementList 
    { 
        get { return dayOfWeekElementList; }
        set 
        { 
        dayOfWeekElementList = value;
        RecalcWeekTasks();
        NotifyPropertyChanged("DayOfWeekElementList");
        } 
    }
```

Bottom class:

```
public class DayOfWeekElement
{
    public string Name { get { return this.DayOfWeek.ToStringValue(); } }
    public bool IsNotEmpty { get { return (TaskCounter > 0); } }
    public int TaskCounter { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#United%20States%20%28English%29) property of the ListBox control.

A possible implementation could be this:

1. Subscribe to the event `SelectedIndexChanged` of the ListBox.
2. Get the selected item.
3. For the selected item, change its `IsActive` property to `true`.

This works if the interface [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#fbid=5yWnr75jKIO) is implemented in your data class.

E.g.:

```
public class DayOfWeekElement : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
       if (PropertyChanged != null)
       {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
   }


   private bool isActive = false;
   public bool IsActive { 
      get
      {
          return this.isActive;
      } 
      set
      {
          if (value != this.isActive)
          {
             this.isActive= value;
             NotifyPropertyChanged("IsActive");
          }
      }  
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but it won't change my checkbox state. (But "isActive" will be changed). What can I do to "refresh" chackbox state? (Do you need more code from me?)

Comment: @interneo I was sure you implemented the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#fbid=5yWnr75jKIO) interface in your data class. Are you implementing this interface in your data class and call the related event for your properties?

Comment: @interneo Thanks. The interface must be implemented also in your `DayOfWeekElement` class and the event `NotifyPropertyChanged` must be called for each property of your class. Have a look at the example in the documentation link I provided you.